# Amplify Auth in Android, cannot access admin queries API

Tags: android, authorization, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I am using the Amplify Auth category which includes an Admin Queries Api but cannot access the api.

In Postman, I test the endpoint with the GET method:

> https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/getUser/?username=jan

(I have a cognito user called jan that is in the admin group). I include an Authorization header with the users id token as a value. (the id token value works when using it to test the api gateway authorizer in the api gateway console). Postman returns a 401 unauthorized status. Nothing displays in Cloudwatch.

In the Api Gateway console, when testing the api's any resources action, I use these settings:

```
  method: GET,
  path {proxy}: getUser,
  query strings {proxy}: username=jan,
  headers {proxy}: Authorization:id token
```

The result indicates **Successfully completed execution**, **Method completed with status: 500** but returns **"message": "Cannot read property 'claims' of undefined"**

The lambda execution is displayed in Cloudwatch.

appreciate any help.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing the path to /getUser instead of just getUser?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the 500 error is because Api gateway isn't forwarding the Cognito authenticated user properly.

The `AdminQueries` Lambda is probably failing at [`req.apiGateway.event.requestContext.authorizer.claims["cognito:groups"]`](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/blob/master/packages/amplify-category-auth/resources/adminAuth/admin-auth-app.js#L57), which is setup to check against all routes.

[How to Create an Authenticated REST API on AWS with API Gateway, Lambda, Cognito, & AWS Amplify](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fs9HfYbWjXQ) helped me get things setup.